# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement awsebcli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

Error:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement awsebcli (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for awsebcli

python version: 3.4.4rc1
pip version: pip 7.1.2 from c:\python34\lib\site-packages (python 3.4)

Answer (score 0):

Could you be a little more specific?  What OS are you on? What are the exact repro steps (in sequence, what did you do?).  Is there documentation you are referring to where the steps are incomplete or leading to this error?

Also might worth be referring to the following: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2160, which may resolve your issue.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: windows 10 64 bit OS. I followed 
 following doc .. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html

Comment: A couple of notes: The documentation @ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-windows.html provides step-by-step instructions on how to install Python, pip, and the CLI on Windows.  I installed Python 3.4.4rc1 and only had to add a couple of additional entries to the PATH environment variable for everything to work: 
-C:\Python34
-C:\Python34\Scripts
-%USERPROFILE%\AppData\roaming\Python\scripts

Comment: Opening a command prompt and typing python --version returned Python 3.4.4rc1, typing pip --version returned pip 7.1.2 from c:\python34\lib\site-packages (python 3.4), and typing eb --version returned EB CLI 3.12.0 (Python 3.4.4).  I was not able to repro the problem you encountered.

Comment: @GaneshRaju - let me know if the above was able to help or you are still having issues.

Comment: @JonathanHeld - I am still having same issues.. and also i tried with python 3.6.2..

Comment: pip list -- it having,  pip (9.0.1),
setuptools (28.8.0),
virtualenv (15.1.0),
virtualenvwrapper-win (1.2.1)